# Create Google Maps MarkerImage from SVG in DOM

Tags: jquery, node.js, google-maps, d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying to create a dynamic SVG marker (basically having the text part of the SVG change for each marker) in Google Maps, but I'm struggling with the dynamic aspect of it. As you can see in the code below, I can create an SVG marker using `new google.maps.MarkerImage()` from a static url.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4269929, -81.7921109),
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64084190/test-marker.svg',
    null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(25, 25)),
    map: map
});
```

But I can't seem to get the `google.maps.MarkerImage()` to take the inner html of a SVG DOM element as its first argument - it is always looking for a URL.

```
<svg id="svg_elem"></svg>

function createDynamicSVGMarker(id){
    var svg_elem = d3.select('#svg_elem');
    svg_elem.append('path')
        .attr('fill', "#3875D7")
        .attr('d', "M100 0h-100v100h36.768l13.431 19.876 13.431-19.876h36.37z");
    svg_elem.append('text')
        .attr('transform', "translate(30.979 80)")
        .attr("fill", "#fff")
        .attr("font-size", "36")
        .text(id);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4269929, -81.7921109),
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage($('#svg_elem').html(),
        null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(25, 25)),
        map: map
    });
    $('#svg_elem').empty();
}
```

Should I be using `MarkerImage` or is there a better approach to tackling this problem? I have tried to do this in node.js (but ultimately failed) - creating a new SVG for each id (or even creating the SVG and then saving as a PNG) - but I thought it would be more efficient to do everything on the client side. I'm open to suggestions using node.js or client side code.

Answer (score 0):

`MarkerImage` has been deprecated in Maps v3.

In any case, check out [Symbols from the Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols), and then [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom):

Based on that example, try this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4269929, -81.7921109),
    icon: {
        path: $('#svg_elem').attr('d'),
        //style elements: fillColor, strokeWeight, etc
        // ...
    },
    map: map
});
```

I'm not sure if you can get everything you'd like in one SVG path (text, etc) but that should get you most of the way there. There are other methods in the Google Maps API that may be able to get the text on top without too much hassle.

Comment: Thanks @TerryTate. I have tried that with the path of the polygon part of the SVG and it works well, but getting my dynamic text on the marker is where I have not been successful.

Comment: No problem. If the svg portion is working, can you post what you've tried for adding text?

Answer (score 0):

After running into the above snafu with google maps, I just decided to start using Leaflet, CSS3, and `L.divIcon`, see my solution below.

```
.markerIcon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
}

.markerIcon .arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 8px solid #446cff;
}

.markerIcon .top {
    color: white;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #446cff;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

<div class="markerHolder" style="display: none">
    <div class="markerIcon">
        <div class="top">HEADER<br><span id="value">888</span></div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>

var $marker = $('#value').text('99');
var marker = new ftzMarker(L.latLng(lat, lng), {
    icon: L.divIcon({
        html: $('.markerHolder').html()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of, is having to create two markers, one with the image and another with the text and add the text marker at the same anchor as the image marker, but a layer above it. This will require some functions for binding the two markers if you want the marker to be draggable(an event listener that listens to one marker, gets it's coords, and assigns the coords to the second marker so it is moved as well. Tricky, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which might be helpful in this case.

You can use an alternative 'URL' with base64 encoded svg:

```
var svg = '<svg width="400" height="110"><rect width="300" height="100" /></svg>';
icon.url = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(svg);
```

JavaScript (Firefox) btoa() is used to get the base64 encoding from the SVG text. Your may also use http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php to generate base data URLs.

Here is a full example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttLu41ok/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var template = [
                '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
                    '<svg width="26px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">',
                        '<circle stroke="#222" fill="{{ color }}" cx="50" cy="50" r="35"/>',
                    '</svg>'
                ].join('\n');
            var svg = template.replace('{{ color }}', '#800');

            var docMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                map: map,
                title: 'Dynamic SVG Marker',
                icon: { url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(svg) }
              });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Additional Information and an other solution using `InfoBox` can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6505).

Although this answer might be too late for you, it might help others looking for a solution to the same problem.